# UIBarButtonItem Not Visible in QLPreviewController Toolbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a subclass of QLPreviewController that I'm pushing into a UINavigationController.  I am able to show/hide the bottom toolbar using:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
}
```

But items I'm adding to the toolbar aren't showing up:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *testButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test"
                                                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                      target:self
                                                                      action:@selector(testButtonClicked:)];

    NSArray *myToolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:testButtonItem, nil];
    self.toolbarItems       = myToolbarItems;
    [testButtonItem release];
}
```

Any advice would be very appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I was able to get UIBarButtons to display in the toolbar by setting the toolbarItems property in the QLPreviewControllerDataSource method:    - (id)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)previewController previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)idx[br][br]However, I have run into another problem.  If I push another view controller on top of the QLPreviewController and then pop if off (back to the QLPreviewController) I get an exception when I call [super viewWillAppear:animated].  Guessing this has something to do with QLPreviewController being able to display an array of previews.

Comment: Update:  Whenever I push a UIViewController on top of a QLPreviewController that is in a UINavigationController and then pop the UIVIewController, I get an exception when the QLPreviewController is re-displayed.  Strange thing is that it only happens on iPhone, not iPad -- both using 4.3.  I confirmed that the delegate method 'previewControllerDidDismiss:' is getting called when running on an iPhone; the delegate method doesn't get called when pushing/popping VCs when running on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you allocating and initializing that view that is giving you the problem?

Are you using a `splitViewController` on iPad?

From the sound of it an object is sticking around for longer than necessary or when being called back it is not being re allocated and initialized properly before attempting to put it back on the stack, if you are using a splitViewController on iPad it handles it's views differently than a simple UINavigationController on an iPhone.